# Exporting DataTable with python to outlook mail

Tags: python, email, datatable, email-attachments, plotly-dash

I am having a tough time finding a way to export a pre-formated DataTable from my Dash WebApp to an outlook e-mail body.
I format the DataTable with conditional formatting and i am trying to add a button to the dash webapp with a callback that will grab the DataTable and export a snapshot of it into an outlook e-mail body so that i may send it to whoever needs to receive the email.

Bellow example is based on a dummy data frame that i import from a dummy excel file into python via pandas and then transform into a Datatable with **dash_table** just for the purpose of giving you an example with the code i have worked on so far:

**Dataframe:**

```
**Name**   **Status**     **Age**
John        Working         31
Michael     Not working     35
Luke        Working         39
Steven      Working         28
```

**DataTable generating code below:**

```
import pandas as pd
import dash_table

df = pd.read_excel ('PATH TO MY EXCEL FILE')

tbl = dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{'name':i,'id':i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        sort_action='native',
        filter_action="native",
        sort_mode='multi',
        page_action='native',
        page_current=0,
        page_size=5,
        style_data={
            'whiteSpace': 'normal',
            'height': '1px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
        },
        style_header={
            'backgroundColor': 'DarkSlateGray',
            'fontWeight': 'bold',
            'color': 'white',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'border': '2px solid grey',
            'padding': '0.5rem 0rem 0rem 0.5rem',
        },
        style_cell={'border': '2px solid DarkSlateGray',
                    'overflow': 'hidden',
                    'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
                    'height': '1rem',
                    'font-size': '12px',
                    'font-family': 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                    'font-weight': 'bold'},
        style_data_conditional = [
            {
                'if': {
                    'filter_query': '{Status} contains "Working"',
                },
                'border': '3px solid DarkSlateGray',
                'backgroundColor': 'lightgreen'
            },
        ],
)
```

Code to create outlook item and paste the DataTable in the body of the e-mail:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime

subject = "Email test: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now())

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'EMAIL ADRESS'
mail.CC = 'EMAIL ADDRESS'
mail.Subject = subject
mail.HtmlBody = tbl
mail.Display(False)
```

**Error i get:**
*AttributeError: Property 'CreateItem.HtmlBody' can not be set.*

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?
(i would need to have the table in the body of the e-mail with the same formatting as the Dash DataTable - which will contain multiple conditional formatting instructions in the actual script - here i have only written 1 to keep the example here as simple as possible).

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Cheers!

Comment: anybody able to help? :(

Comment: Your error is coming from the `win32` package you're using. You may want to retag this question to include that or some kind of e-mail related tag.

Comment: @coralvanda but when i run the same script with a string instead of the table the e-mail is generated. So how is the error coming from the win32 package?

Comment: Ok. The error is misleading, then. In that case, can you dump the table as a JSON object? If a string works, JSON should work, too.